# Get name attribute of character vector by element name

Tags: r, vector, attributes, character

```
x <- c("one", "two")
attr(x, "names") <- c("eins", "zwei")
```

Now I would like to get the name attribute of `one` only:

```
x$one
# Error in x$one : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
attr(x, "names")$one
# Error in attr(x, "names")$one : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

What should I do?

Comment: Could `x["eins"]` help? Or `x[attr(x, "names") %in% "eins"]`? If you check (and you should check) `class(attr(x, "names")`, it says that is is `character`, not `data.frame`, as you think it is.

Comment: I know it's a character - hence the title. I just didn't find advice on slicing of character vectors.

Comment: Be happy, I gave you a better advice than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
x <- c("one", "two")
attr(x, "names") <- c("eins", "zwei")

> attr(x, "names")[1]
[1] "eins"
```

Or this:

```
> attr(x[x=="one"],"names")
> [1] "eins"
```

*edit

If you are only interested in the name attribute you could also use:

```
names(x[x=="one"])
```

in order to get the desired result.

Comment: Please add also the use of `names<-` which is to be preferred to `attr(,"names")<-`. I think that `names(x[x=="one"])` is cleaner. +1.

Comment: I wanted to give a more general solution. But you are right in this case this would be preferable.